# I am closing and disposing a locally declared streamwriter, but I'm still getting file use by another process exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-io, stream

Am trying to achieve a couple of things:

1. merge a bunch of individual text files into a combined file,
2. move the files that were combined into a new folder.

I have assigned each of these tasks to a method.

Something in the first method is hanging on to the file, even though I am closing and disposing the stream reader - but I can't figure out what. I know that a process from the first method is hanging on to the file because when I comment out the first method, the second method moves the files without a problem.

**EDIT** *The first method is returning a value for new big file. This is passed as a parameter to the second method. When the second method tries to reference this file, that is when the program throws the error (5th line from bottom)*

Most posts on SO advise closing/disposing IO objects, but I am already doing that. They also advise using a third party tool to investigate what process is hanging on to a file, but I already know that it is the first merge method (because when it is commented out the program runs).

This is an example similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088225/file-use-by-another-process-exception-in-c-sharp

What am I missing?

```
newBigFile as string = mergeFiles (inputLocation, outputLocation) 
moveFiles = moveMergedFiles(inputLocation, outputLocation, newBigFile)

Private Function mergeFiles(ByVal inputLocationFilesToMerge As String, ByVal outputLocationHL7 As String) As String


    Dim newMergedFile As String = inputLocationFilesToMerge & "\jointFile" & DateTime.Now.Month & DateTime.Now.Day & DateTime.Now.Year & DateTime.Now.Hour & DateTime.Now.Minute & ".hl7"
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(newMergedFile)
    Dim HL7FilePaths As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inputLocationFilesToMerge, "*.hl7")

    For Each p As String In HL7FilePaths
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(p)
        objWriter.Write(sr)
        sr.Close()
        sr.Dispose()
    Next

    objWriter.Close()
    objWriter.Dispose()

    Return (newMergedFile) 

End Function

Private Sub moveMergedFiles(ByVal inputLocationFilesToMerge As String, ByVal outputLocationHL7 As String, ByVal mergedFile As String)


    For Each q As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inputLocationFilesToMerge, "*.hl7")
        If (Not (q = mergedFile)) Then **this is where the error comes from**
            File.Move(q, outputLocationHL7 & "\" & Path.GetFileName(q)) 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well this is VB code.. so are you using C# or VB

Comment: VB. My understanding is the the languages are just different syntaxes on top of the same .NET framework. Right?

Comment: No completely true.. VB and C# are nothing alike.. that's why we all do C#.. it's better in many developers opinions... also how come you have to fully qualify System.IO.Drirectory. can you add System.IO to the header I would also suggest making your variables Methods and properties more readable.. it's hard to follow single character variable not to mention messy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line `objWriter.Write(sr)` shouldn't you call `sr.ReadToEnd()`? Seems like you're passing the streamReader object rather than the stream data (unless there is an implicit cast that I am unaware of).

If memory is not a concern, maybe try substituting the StreamReader for a quick `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`. At least this way you can see if it is the streamReader or not.

Comment: I made that change but it did not fiX it unfortunately

Comment: @akh2103 If memory is not a concern maybe try substituting the StreamReader for a quick `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`. At least this way you can see if it is the streamReader or not.

Comment: It must have been a problem with the Streamreaders/writers. I just used File.ReadAllText and File.WriteAllText like you suggested and it solved the problem. Why do you say "if memory is not a concern"? Because if the files are really big then you need to read the input data in as a stream rather than all at once or it will break your program? Or because the File.Read/write methods are less efficient?  Do you want to add your commented suggestion to your answer so I can accept?

Comment: @akh2103 Streams are often used so that you only have to keep a small number of bytes in memory at a time rather than reading all of the data into memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(newMergedFile)
```

Where else in code is this being used? - Usually this is caused because you are creating too many new Instances and or the Stream of that file is still open just create a Global instance of `objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(newMergedFile)`

Then when done Close that with `objWriter.Close()` I am backing out of this one.. code looks way to messing and lacks clear thought and direction..

Comment: That method is the only place in the code using object writer.

Comment: Also instead of objWriter.Write look to see if there is a WriteLine and for sr see if there is a sr.WriteAllLines or ReadAllLines you you are trying to write to a file but the way you are doing it .. it's not very clean.. in your forEach loop move the Dim of the writer outside of the For loop remove the sr.Dispose() and just null it and dispose after the loop

Answer (score 0):

You aren't disposing of objwriter.
I'd also suggest you use FileStream for physical files

and last but far from least important using

So in C# (ish) as I'm not a VB head

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newMergedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    TextWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
    foreach(String fileName in HL7FilePaths)
    {
        using (FileStream frs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            ObjWriter.AppendStream(frs);
            ObjWriter.Flush(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Can't remember the exact syntax for new FileStream, Create and ReadWrite for the merged file and Open and read for FileMode, and FileAccess or somesuch usually do the job.

Just a habit we've developed, always use a using block, that will close and dispose for you, Flush() to make sure, and FileStream will fail trying to get the file if there's anything wrong well before you try to read or write.

Rarely get file problems, if you follow something like this path.

Comment: Wee amendment as Stream isn't an acceptable argument for StreamWriter

Answer (score 0):

Two problems...
1) You are trying to open the jointFile for reading when it is being used to write to.
2) You need to read the file with a sr.ReadToEnd as stated by ach

Change:

```
For Each p As String In HL7FilePaths      
     Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(p)   
     objWriter.Write(sr)           
     sr.Close()
     sr.Dispose()       
Next
```

To:

```
For Each p As String In HL7FilePaths
            If p <> newMergedFile Then
                Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(p)
                objWriter.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)
                sr.Close()
                sr.Dispose()
            End If
Next
```